# Processing data in a distributed environment without any duplicate execution

Tags: redis, parallel-processing, devops, distributed-computing, redis-cluster

I am planning to develop a fault tolerant crypto trading bot which takes buy/sell targets from user and executes it when market price reaches the target

**Idea:**
My idea is to store the trade targets (buy/sell) in both MongoDB and Redis database. An independent Go application ("Market Listener & Trade Executor") always listen to the realtime market data (from binance) and trade targets (from redis). When condition matches, the trade should be executed.

**Goal:**

- When one or more node is down, still trade should be executed properly when condition met
- A trade shouldn't be executed twice at any cost
- Trade should be executed in near real time

**Problem/Challenges:**

- How to ensure, in distributed environment one trade targets is exactly being processed by one node to avoid any duplicate trade execution
- If any node is down, how to process the trade targets in other available nodes

Any solution or help is highly appreciated. Share any information that could help me to solve this problem. Open to different approach as well. Thanks!

**High-level Diagram:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While still being actively developed if you want once only - [Redis Raft](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisraft) or some other Raft based datastore might serve you best